# @SqlResultSetMapping with @Embedded

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I hava a problem with mapping embedded fields in Hibernate.
This is the code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CAR")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "carMapping",
entities = {
    @EntityResult(entityClass = Car.class,
fields = {
    @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "ID"),
    @FieldResult(name = "producer", column = "PRODUCER"),
    @FieldResult(name = "model", column = "MODEL"),

    @FieldResult(name="bookNumber",column="SERVICE_BOOK_NUMBER"),
    @FieldResult(name="owner", column="SERVICE_BOOK_OWNER")
}
)})
public class Car {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name="PRODUCER")
private String producer;

@Column(name="MODEL")
private String model;

@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="bookNumber", column=@Column(name="SERVICE_BOOK_NUMBER")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="owner", column=@Column(name="SERVICE_BOOK_OWNER")),
})
private ServiceBook serviceBook;
```

When I try to retrive a Car I get the following error:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: The transaction has been marked rollback only 
because the bean encountered a non-application exception :javax.persistence.PersistenceException : 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Column 'SERVICE4_0_0_' not found
```

My question is: is it possible to use `@SqlResultSetMapping` and `@Embedded` together?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new @EntityResult to ServiceBook such as you did with Car.class. I usually do this to bind columns to the attributes.